Minimal-partition number of any integer
I was wondering if someone knows about the following problem (or math puzzle, I'd say) and its solutions:
Let $N$ be a positive integer. We split $N$ into $m$ groups, i.e., we choose a non-decreasing subset of positive integers $\{S_i\}_{i=1}^{m} \subset \mathbb{N}$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{m}S_i = N$. Then we define a number $\mathrm{Min}(N)$ by the least $m$ satifying the condition that for every integer $M \in \{1,\cdots, N\}$, we can always find a subset $\{S_{i(k)}\}_{k=1}^{m'} \subset \{S_i\}_{i=1}^{\mathrm{Min}(N)}$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^{m'}S_{i(k)} = M$. We may call such a subset $\{S_i\}_{i=1}^{\mathrm{Min}(N)}$ the "minimal partition" of $N$.
For example, if $N=8$, then $\mathrm{Min}(N)=4$ and one of its minimal partition is given by $\{1,1,2,4\}$ (the partition is not unique). Indeed, we can make every number from 1 to 8 by choosing some of the numbers in $\{1,1,2,4\}$; however, $\{1,2,5\}$ is not a minimal partition because we cannot make 4 by choosing some of the numbers in $\{1,2,5\}$.
My first question is this: what can we say about $\mathrm{Min}(N)$?
(I've been notified that the same question as mine was already answered [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4393138/how-to-split-a-natural-number-x-into-components-such-that-they-sum-to-x-and])
My second question is this: what is the deep connection (if any) between this problem and other topics in combinatorics, number theory, etc.?
I think that there are relations between this puzle and the so-called minimal excludant (see, for instance, https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00026-019-00427-w).
I'd be very glad if you enjoy the puzzle and tell me any suggestion or comment.
Thank you for your time.
